# How can I complete the criteria and keep it compact?

Tags: python

Here is my code, something I have been working on for awhile as work.
I'm trying to determine certain characteristics of a game character using numbers on a combination of dice, like in a DnD style game. By rolling a 12 and 4 sided dice, then dividing the outcome, I then add this to the base stat of 10 to get the improved stat, then I am suppose to round down to a whole number without decimals; then save this information to an external document.

I'm really bad as you can see. I want to have a compact piece of code, so I want to be able to get the stats of the two character without having to double my code, can anyone give some tips to be able to do this? The two characters names should be Steve and Jenny.

```
import random
import time

character1 = ("Steve")
character2 = ("Jenny")

y = 0

while y <3:
    x = 0
    y += 1
    numlist = []

while x <5:
    x += 1
    four = random.randint (1,4)
    twelve = random.randint (1,12)
    newint = 10 + twelve /four
    numlist.append (newint)

strength = numlist[0]
skill = numlist[1]
health = numlist[2]
dexterity = numlist[3]

round (strength, 10)
round (skill, 10)
round (health, 10)
round (dexterity, 10)

print (strength)
print (skill)
print (health)
print (dexterity)

strength = str(strength)
skill = str(skill)
health = str(health)
dexterity = str(dexterity)

doc = open ("character1", "w")
doc.write ("Strength is ")
doc.write (strength )
doc.write (", ")
doc.write ("Skill is ")
doc.write (skill )
doc.write (", ")
doc.write ("Health is ")
doc.write (health )
doc.write (", ")
doc.write ("Dexterity is ")
doc.write (dexterity )
doc.write (".")
doc.close()
```

Comment: What about writing some function? http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm

Comment: `round(strength, 10)` does not do anything. Try `strength = round(strength, 10)`. Also, what is your `while y` loop supposed to do?

Comment: ... and the first `while` loop is "curious"

Comment: About your question by itself now: maybe you should *edit your question* to focus on only one characteristic. Explain the rules to determine that characteristic. And show us how you addressed *that particular point*. That would lower the "distracting noise". And would allow us to provide -- and debates -- various alternatives.

Comment: Does your code do everything you want?

Comment: No, I also need the code to repeat itself if a new character is needed, and save the new stats for the new character in a new document.

Comment: All the answers below doesn't really help the OP learn anything about Python, what he's doing and why. A sheer code writing service. The question is "How can I", not "Can you do that for me".

Comment: @Germano: Thanks, you're completely correct, the majourity of the codes I've been shown I have no clue what they actually mean

Comment: Well, at least the OP can study possible solutions and gather more detailed information by googling the commands or asking specific questions. In my opinion, there's no point in writing a lengthy tutorial on a very specific application like this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version, which I wrote parallel to naiad:

```
import random

def roll():
    return 10 + int(random.randint(1, 12) / random.randint(1, 4))

def newCharacter(name):
    character = dict(name = name, strength = roll(), skill = roll(), health = roll(), dexterity = roll())
    print character
    return character

def saveCharacter(filename, character):
    with open(filename, "w") as doc:
        doc.write("Strength is %d, " % character["strength"])
        doc.write("Skill is %d, " % character["skill"])
        doc.write("Health is %d, " % character["health"])
        doc.write("Dexterity is %d." % character["dexterity"])

saveCharacter("character1.txt", newCharacter("Steve"))
saveCharacter("character2.txt", newCharacter("Jenny"))
```

**Further reading:**

- Functions in Python (and the `return` statement):

  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm
- Formatting strings (via the `%` operator):

  https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting

  (Feel free to use any other string formatting technique, like `"abc " + str(number)` or `"abc {0}".format(number)`.)
- Reading and writing files:

  https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files
- Dictionaries:

  https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict

Comment: I need the output as a .txt, how would this be done?

The output of

`{'dexterity': 12.75, 'skill': 13.0, 'strength': 10.5, 'health': 12.5, 'name': 'Steve'} {'dexterity': 12.25, 'skill': 11.0, 'strength': 19.0, 'health': 11.0, 'name': 'Jenny'}`

Is fairly confusing also, is there any way to separate the different attributes to different lines?

Comment: @Silver: So you only need one txt containing the "{...} {...}" output? As it is, no new line etc.?

Comment: I need the code to repeat itself if a new character is needed, and save the new stats for the new character in a new document.

I would like the document to be saved like
`Strength is _, Skill is _, Health is _, Dexterity is _`, without the {}

Comment: @Silver: This is already done. The file is just named "character1/2" without ending - exactly like you did in your example. Simply call ```saveCharacter("character1.txt, character1)``` and you get a txt.

Comment: I also said I need to round down the numbers to the nearest possible whole number, how would this be done in your code?

Comment: @Silver: I further simplified the code so that you only need to execute one line for a new character. It generates a new one, prints it to the command line and saves it to a txt file with specified name.

Comment: @Silver: Fixed it using the ```int(...)``` function.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, but this code is far out of my ability, do you mind using # to describe what lines are doing, more specifically the `return` command and `%`?

Comment: @Silver: Extensive comments would probably make the code unreadable. Therefore I added some references for further reading. There are many good tutorials and reference documents on the Python language, so you probably find what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [classes](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) in case of further improvements:

```
import random

class Character(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.stats = {'strength': 0,
                      'dexterity': 0,
                      'health': 0,
                      'skill': 0,
                     }

    @staticmethod
    def roll():
        return int(10 + random.randint(1, 12) / random.randint(1, 4))

    def generate_stats(self):
        for stat in self.stats:
            self.stats[stat] = self.roll()

    def export_stats(self):
        with open(self.name + '.txt', 'w') as output:
            for stat in self.stats:
                output.write('{0}: {1}\n'.format(stat, self.stats[stat]))


for name in ('Steve', 'Jenny'):
    character = Character(name)
    character.generate_stats()
    character.export_stats()
```